# Issues while reading XML file

Tags: java, xml, filereader

I have an XML file which is of the format

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE PRG-TXT[]><PRG-TXT
ANKER="PLOAlertCannotPerform_ApparentIn"
WERT="AlertCannotPerform_ApparentIntersection"
><PRG-TXT-STD
><PRG-TXT-INHALT
>Kann keinen scheinbaren Schnittpunkt mit den gewählten Linien berechnen.</PRG-TXT-INHALT
></PRG-TXT-STD
></PRG-TXT
>
```

While trying to read the contents of the file using `BufferedReader` or any file reader, this is the output that I'm seeing:
[image]

**EDIT:**
    If I copy-paste the xml file content into notepad & again (from notepad) copy-paste it back to the original file, then I see the output correctly.

Not understanding this weird behavior.

**Code:**

```
BufferedReader file = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
String line;
String input = "";

while ((line = file.readLine()) != null)
{
    System.out.println(line.toString()); 
}

file.close();
```

Comment: Please show the code that you're using, and include the output within the question rather than as a separate file. It looks like the file may be in UTF-16 instead of the advertised UTF-8 though - where did you get it from?

Comment: @JonSkeet Hi, am not able to copy the output, So linked an image of it. And am using normal file reader code. Will add for your reference. Thank You.

Comment: Please don't quote code like that - it just needs to be indented by four spaces to be shown as code. And what do you mean by "am not able to copy the output"? What happens when you try? Now, you're using `FileReader`, which uses the default character encoding for your system - what is that encoding? (It would be better to use a `FileinputStream` and an `InputStreamReader` so you could specify the encoding - or better yet, use an XML parser, given that it's XML.) We still don't know where you got the file from, or how you're seeing it in a "normal" form...

Comment: "I'm not able copy"  I mean: I copy it & when I try to paste, Nothing is pasted. I get the same output again with FIS and ISR ! Thank You.

Comment: Again, you really should be using an XML parser instead - but you should *also* find out where the file came from (as I've asked twice already) and get the source to fix it - it looks like it's simply invalid at the moment, claiming to be UTF-8 without *actually* being UTF-8.

Comment: I got the file from some random source (internet),  I'm already using SAX parser but since there seem to be some problem with XML file, it is throwing exceptions. Like I said, if I just do copy-paste of xml file contents into text editor & copy-paste it back to the original xml file, then I see correct output.

Comment: Right, so the file is broken or the way you've downloaded it is broken. It's possible that explicitly loading it using an `InputStreamReader` set to UTF-16 will work, but you really shouldn't have to do that. If you've already found a workaround to read that specific file (fixing it, basically) why not just use that?

Comment: Thanks for all your time Jon, tried to figure it out but couldn't find a solution yet.

Comment: Hey !! UTF-16 worked !! Thanks a Tonn !